# Android Studio - Use of radio buttons to calculate user input and display from button

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get my converter app to work but I'm having trouble.
The app is supposed to take user input and then, depending on what radio button the user has selected, will then calculate the user input with radio button specific calculations and then displayed in a TextView when the user clicks the 'convert' button.

Currently, the radio buttons select calculations but it doesn't calculate correctly and I'm sure its a simple process to fix it but I can't find it.

Here's my code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/neo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Amount"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupCurrencies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonZar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="ZAR" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonNeo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioGroupCurrencies"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="NEO" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
        android:text="Convert" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonConvert"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonConvert"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
        android:text="Clear" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOutput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonConvert"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.NumberFormat;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioButton zar, neo;
    Double zarAmount;
    Double neoAmount;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(final View view) {
        final boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        EditText editTextUser = findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
        final TextView textViewOuput = findViewById(R.id.textViewOutput);
        final Double userInput = Double.parseDouble(editTextUser.getText().toString());

        zar = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonZar);
        neo = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonNeo);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NumberFormat nm = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radioButtonZar:
                if(checked)
                    zarAmount = (userInput * 833.44);
                    textViewOuput.setText(nm.format(zarAmount));

                break;
            case R.id.radioButtonNeo:
                if(checked)
                    neoAmount = (userInput / 0.001199);
                    textViewOuput.setText(nm.format(neoAmount));
                break;

        }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I've done anything wrong, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change recuperation of userInput inside of click button

```
    final Double userInput = Double.parseDouble(editTextUser.getText().toString());
```

There is code of onRadioButtonClicked

```
 public void onRadioButtonClicked(final View view) {
    final boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    final EditText editTextUser = findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
    final TextView textViewOuput = findViewById(R.id.textViewOutput);


    zar = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonZar);
    neo = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonNeo);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NumberFormat nm = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
            final Double userInput = Double.parseDouble(editTextUser.getText().toString());
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.radioButtonZar:
                    if(checked)
                        zarAmount = (userInput * 833.44);
                    textViewOuput.setText(nm.format(zarAmount));

                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonNeo:
                    if(checked)
                        neoAmount = (userInput / 0.001199);
                    textViewOuput.setText(nm.format(neoAmount));
                    break;

            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have another observation you have to verify if editTextUser.getText().toString() is different of null before parsing Double to prevent crash

Hope this helpful :)

Comment: Thanks, at least it runs and doesn't crash now. Problem is the second calculation is off for neoAmount. It doesn't divide the user's input by 0.001199. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have to add 
final Double userInput = Double.parseDouble(editTextUser.getText().toString());
Inside your OnClick not in onRadioButtonClicked